# How to add FaceID for family members to iPhones

Tags: iphone, login, touch-id, face-id

We only have cellular phones in our home and with our older phones my wife and I could add TouchIDs to each of our phones, and add our children's fingerprints as well.  So, anyone could quickly use either phone.  It's not just a matter of convenience, but also if there is an urgent matter... perhaps not a 911 emergency, but an emergency none the less, our children can quickly use the phones to get help.

Anyhow, with our new iPhone X, I cannot find how to train it to open for more than one face.  How can we add FaceID for family members to our iPhones now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone X currently does not support multi-face authentication. You can only add one face now. It may be or may not be added in the future updates. As per a mail sent by Apple VP Craig Federighi, it's unlikely that Apple will add this in future. You can read the mail from him in below link at MacRumors.

[Mail from Craig Federighi](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/12/01/craig-federighi-face-id-touch-id-email/)

Comment: Wow, that seems like a bizarre, gross misunderstanding with how families use phones.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Very disappointing.  We've found that the only safe solution is for everyone to learn the passcode.  Disappointing because the passcode functions like a master password for the device, and it's just not as fast to use at all.

Comment: It's disappointing as I am in the same situation as you. With TouchID, my family could access the old iPhone, but with X,  only I can use with without password.

Comment: I've been reading more about it.  So far I've seen 3 perspectives.  
1. Apple: Probably can sell more devices by removing the ability to share devices
2. Apathetic: "For reasons... don't like to share my device with family members"/"Children shouldn't be able to use a phone" So, they don't care that other family members cannot easily access it.
3. Families: These are devices that any member of the family, especially parents, should be able to pick up and access quickly and easily for numerous logical reasons